# Grails 3 : console plugin not coming up in production mode

Tags: grails, console, asset-pipeline, grails3.2.0

Grails console plugin page is not coming up nothing gets rendered on the UI only when application is run on production environment either via run-app or as a war file deployed on embedded tomcat.

Grails version - 3.2.4

build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        maven {  url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }

    }
    dependencies {
        ....
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.13.1"
       ...
    }
}

version "0.1"

apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
}


dependencies {
    ....
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.0.9'
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.13.1"
    ....
}
```

Any thoughts whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

By default the plugin is disabled in production for obvious reasons (an attacker could do anything to your app) - but if you understand the risk and secure it you can re-enable it. Checkout the documentation here https://github.com/sheehan/grails-console#security